# The Klein bottle can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: general-topology, klein-bottle

How can one show that the Klein bottle can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

We define the Klein bottle as the quotient space of $I^2=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ under the relation $\sim$ for which $(0,y)\sim (1,1-y)$ and $(x,0)\sim (x,1)$.

If we found a continuous $f:I^2\to R^k$ which is constant over the fibers of $\pi:I^2\to I^2/{\sim}$ then we'd have a continuous $g:I^2/{\sim}\to\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $g\pi=f$.

What do I need for $g$ to be an immersion? And to be an embedding?

How can I show that there is an immersion for $k=3$ and an embedding for $k=4$ (without finding it explicitly)?

Comment: An immersion is a "local homeomorphism", where each point of the Klein bottle has a neighbourhood that is mapped homeomorphically onto its image in $\Bbb R^k$. An embedding is a homeomorphism on all of its image. In particular, it needs to be injective. So any embedding is an immersion, but an immersion might have self-intersections, like the [common Klein bottle immersions](https://www.google.com/search?q=klein+bottle&tbm=isch) into $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get around finding it explicitly.

Comment: Can't you just appeal to Whitney embedding for $k = 4$, so you don't have to write an embedding down explicitly?

Comment: @TakumiMurayama No, actually! The general proof of the Whitney embedding theorem is only true for $n$-manifolds, $n>2$. One gets it in low dimensions by hand. The version that embeddings $M \to \Bbb R^5$ are dense in all smooth maps is still perfectly valid, but that's a dimension higher than you want.

Comment: @MikeMiller ah, thank you! This is what I get for quoting theorems I haven't thought about the proof for.